# "Not Enough Fund" when doing buying token transaction in Solidity with Remix IDE

Tags: ethereum, blockchain, solidity, nft, remix

I am completely new to this blockchain world so I want to try learn it. While I am following a tutorial to create a simple ERC-1155 contract to mint a token and set its price. When I am trying to run the buyToken function from another address, it keeps saying "Not Enough Fund". When I debug the msg.value value is 0, even though I have 100 ethers balance on each of my address. When I change the amount of token to 0, it works successfully. What should I need to do to be able to do the transaction?

[Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xSg3N.png)

This is my contract that I have modified on:

```
// Contract based on https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/4.x/erc1155
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.0;
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC1155/ERC1155.sol";

/**
 * @title NFTMinter
 * @dev NFT Contract Minter
 * @custom:dev-run-script ./scripts/deploy_with_ethers.ts
 */
contract NFTMinter is ERC1155 {
  constructor() ERC1155("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/noopmood/TutorialNFTInGo/main/metadata/{id}.json") payable {}
  
  // Define the mapping of addresses to balances
  mapping(address => mapping(uint256 => uint256)) public _balances;

  // Define the mapping of address to tokenIds owned
  mapping(address => uint256[]) public _tokenIds;

  // Define the mapping of tokenId to price
  mapping(uint256 => uint256) public tokenPrice;

  // Define the sender to address payable type
  address payable public sender;

  struct Token {
    uint256 tokenId;
    uint256 balance;
  }

  function mintCaller(uint256 tokenId, uint256 amount) public {
    _mint(msg.sender, tokenId, amount, "");
  }

  // Mints new tokens and sets the price for each token.
  function mintAddress(uint256 tokenId, uint256 amount, address addr, uint256 price) public{
    _mint(addr, tokenId, amount, "");
    // Update the balance of the recipient
    _balances[addr][tokenId] += amount;
     // Add the tokenId to the address
    _tokenIds[addr].push(tokenId);
    // Set the price of the token
    tokenPrice[tokenId] = price;
  }

  // Get all tokenIds from its owner address
  function getTokenIdsByAddress(address addr) public view returns (uint[] memory) {
    return _tokenIds[addr];
  }

  // Get the balance / amount of the tokenId
  function getTokenByIdAndAddress(address addr, uint256 tokenId) public view returns (Token memory) {
    Token memory result;
    result.tokenId = tokenId;
    result.balance = _balances[addr][tokenId];
    return result;
  }

  // Get the tokenIds along with its corresponding balances/amount
  function getAllTokenByAddress(address holder) public view returns (Token[] memory) {
    Token[] memory result = new Token[](_tokenIds[holder].length);
    for (uint i = 0; i < _tokenIds[holder].length; i++) {
      result[i].tokenId = _tokenIds[holder][i];
      result[i].balance = _balances[holder][_tokenIds[holder][i]];
    }
    return result;
  }

  // Transfers the tokens from one address to another.
  function transfer(address addr, uint256 tokenId, uint256 amount) public {
    require(_balances[msg.sender][tokenId] >= amount, "Not enough balance");
    // Transfer the token
    _safeTransferFrom(msg.sender, addr, tokenId, amount, "");
    // Update the sender's balance
    _balances[msg.sender][tokenId] -= amount;
    // Update the recipient's balance
    _balances[addr][tokenId] += amount;
  }

  // Allows a buyer to purchase a token by sending the required amount to the contract and updating the balance of the buyer.
  function buyToken(uint256 tokenId, uint256 amount) public payable {
    require(msg.value >= amount * tokenPrice[tokenId], "Not enough funds");
    // Deduct the amount from the buyer
    sender = payable(msg.sender);
    sender.transfer(amount * tokenPrice[tokenId]);
    // Transfer the token to the buyer
    _safeTransferFrom(address(0), msg.sender, tokenId, amount, "");
    // Update the buyer's balance
    _balances[msg.sender][tokenId] += amount;
  }
}
```

On what the step to reproduce this:

- Deploy the contract with value, for me I pass 20 Ether
- Run the mintAddress function by passing, tokenId: 1, amount: 10, price: 10, address: the address an account
- Run the transfer function by passing address: the address of account you want to transfer the token into, tokenId: 1, amount: 10
- Change the account in upper part to the address you use in transfer function
- Run buyToken function, tokenId: 1, amount: 10
- It will said Not Enough Fund

[buyToken](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rx2yp.png)

What I have tried so far:

- I read in another post, that I should deploy the contract with the value in it. But it still doesn't work
- I have checked that the balance of my account in remix have 100 ethers, but when I try to doing the buy token with it, it still said 'Not Enough Fund'

What I am expecting:
To be able to buy the token with the price that has been set when minting the token.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is failing from here:

```
// require is like if statement. if condition does not satisfied, it shows the passed message
require(msg.value >= amount * tokenPrice[tokenId], "Not enough funds")
```

When a user sends funds alongside the transaction, not as an function argument, solidity will catch it with `msg.value`. Looks like you are not sending any value alongside the transaction or not sending enough funds. in Remix IDE

[image]

you need to pass the necessary value in the above red borderd box

Comment: If I pass the value in ether, is it also affecting the msg.value? Won't it be converting to Wei automatically?

Comment: yes. anything you put in value input, it will be caught as `msg.value`. if u enter ether,  remix will convert it to wei automatically

Comment: I have tried it but it is still not working. 

On what the step to reproduce this:
- Deploy the contract with value, for me I pass 20 Ether
- Run the mintAddress function by passing, tokenId: 1, amount: 10, price: 10, address: the address an account
- Run the transfer function by passing address: the address of account you want to transfer the token into, tokenId: 1, amount: 10
- Change the account in upper part to the address you use in transfer function
- Run buyToken function, tokenId: 1, amount: 10
- It still said Not Enough Fund

Comment: @0391 your original question was about ` buyToken` function. now you are asking about transfer function

Comment: Yes but to proceed to buyToken, I have to transfer the token first and the transferred token address will do the buyToken, which makes the issue occur where they are unable to buy the token

Comment: just be aware that  here you cannot have multiple posts in a question. did you get "Not enough funds"  or "Not enough balance" this time

Comment: Still Not Enough Funds. I am sorry if it became confusing. This is the screenshot of the Not Enough Funds https://i.stack.imgur.com/rx2yp.png

Comment: it prints out "Not enough funds"  from this  ` require(msg.value >= amount * tokenPrice[tokenId], "Not enough funds")` , right? or  "Not Enough Fund"

Comment: Yes Not enough funds from that. I am really sorry I don't think missing one character in a question can make it confusing

Comment: When you call buyToken fn, are you passing value into the input that i showed in the image

Comment: Wait, Do I also have to pass the value when call the function not only when we deploy the contract?

Comment: I think you should start to study the basics first. looks like you are just learning solidity with a complex contract